# ASP.NET Core 1 RC2 web application entry point

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-core

So they changed the way they're bootstrapping web applications between asp.net 5 rc1 and rc2.

It used to be:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
```

But in RC2, I no longer have a reference to the static class WebApplication. Any ideas?

Comment: RC2 is not actually out.  So you're using the RC2 unreleased?

Comment: Yeah, I was using some sample authentication projects that required it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the announcements repo: [Hosting renaming WebApplication to WebHost](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/141)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseDefaultConfiguration(args)
        .UseIISPlatformHandlerUrl()
        .UseStartup("MusicStore")
        .Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

The example is from [MusicStore](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/src/MusicStore/Program.cs#L5-L17)

Comment: UseDefaultConfiguration and UseIISPlatformHandlerUrl are no longer available options.

Answer (score 20):

After reflecting on your question for a while, I think it has three parts.

1. bootstrapping the application,
2. the application entry point, and
3. the change in creating a web host (i.e. this missing `WebApplication`)

## Bootstrapping the application

In rc1 `dnx.exe` bootstraps your application, whereas in `rc2` your compiled console application (`foo.exe`) does the bootstrapping. By bootstrapping, I mean starting up the managed application by creating a process, loading the Core CLR into RAM, and finding your application's entry point. This required `dnx.exe` in rc1 because your web application only pretended to be a console app, whereas in rc2 your web application is a *real console app*, along with its own executable. What makes the console app a web application is that it uses ASP.NET Core libraries.

## Application entry point

In both rc1 and rc2 the application entry point is the `Main()` method. That is where we put the first line of code that we want to run. This makes sense, when we consider that ASP.NET Core runs *within* a console application, and a console application's default entry point is its `Main()` method.

## The hosting class

In both rc1 and rc2 the `Main()` method calls into ASP.NET Core libraries, and the first call to ASP.NET Core code creates the ASP.NET Core host. In rc1 we started this with `WebApplication.Run<SomeClass>()`. In rc2 we instead jump right into adding middleware to the pipeline with a call to `new WebHostBuilder().FluentMiddlewareCall()...Build()`. That's the ASP.NET Core host that we're calling not the application's managed entry point. This is an important distinction.

## Summary

In ASP.NET Core rc2, your application is its own executable with it own bootstrapping code. It's managed entry point is its `Main()` method. It becomes a web application because it references ASP.NET Core libraries and creates a web host using `new WebHostBuilder()`.

```
// application entry point
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    // code here will run before the host. 
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world.");

    // this is the rc1 host call. 
    // WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args); 

    // this is the rc2 host call
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()...

    // you shouldn't do work after the host call.
}
```

## Historical comparison

**In ASP.NET 4.x** The Internet Information Services (IIS) executable (`InetMgr.exe`) loads the Common Language Runtime (CLR) and uses it to create/call a managed web application's entry point. This entry point is the `HttpApplication.Application_Start()` event, which we can handle via Global.asax to add our first line of code.

```
InetMgr.exe > Runtime > HttpApplication/Global.asax > Application_Start()
```

**In ASP.NET Core rc1:** The DNX (`dnx.exe`) executable loads the Core CLR and uses it to create/call our application's `Main()` method. We call `WebApplication` and its `Run<SomeClass>()` method, thereby creating a host and building up an HTTP pipeline.

```
Dnx.exe > Runtime > Main() > WebApplication.Run<SomeClass>() > ...
```

**In ASP.NET Core rc2** Our application's compiled executable (`foo.exe`) loads the Core CLR to create/call our applications `Main()` method. We call `WebHostBuilder()`, thereby creating a host and building up an HTTP pipeline.

```
ConsoleApp.exe > Runtime > Main() > WebHostBuilder() > ...
```

## References

https://vimeo.com/153212604

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/11/18/announcing-net-core-and-asp-net-5-rc

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-structure

Comment: Wow, super helpful. Thanks for the overview of the legacy, RC1, and RC2 runtimes. I'm surprised to see such a major architectural change so late in the ASP.NET Core 1 game.

Comment: I am surprised too and am still wrapping my head around the architectural changes. So, take my answer with a large grain of salt. :)

Comment: This is awesome. It matters little if some details are wrong. There may be further surprises when RC2 actually hits.  The fact that RC2 is not out yet and it's March 3rd now, tells me that the tooling changes are taking longer than expected.  This is a big architectural shift, but it seems like a good one to me.  The new MS.  Development out in the open.  This is how the sausage is made. :-)

Comment: According to ASP.NET Community Standup, there's not going to be a `foo.exe`. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/04/21/notes-from-the-asp-net-community-standup-april-19-2016/

Comment: @VSG24 Cool! How are we going to start the beast of an application without an `foo.exe` on Windows?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin The web application is compiled to a DLL and the dotnet.exe command-line-interface knows how to locate this method and start the application. This structure allows the application to be portable, as the dotnet.exe is native to the operating system and knows how to load the DLL on its platform. The application can be made standalone, but we need to capture information about the target platform that would be compiled to.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfJgGHqVcLI&list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF&index=3

Comment: @VSG24 Are you saying that we ship a native `dotnet` executable, which knows how to locate the `main` method and start the application?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, At this point it's not exactly clear how it will be done in the official release, but I'm pretty sure it will be a cross-platform dll that we ship, either in an executable or without that. Even the asp.net team is not exactly sure how it should be done. Don't forget that because of a recent update to RC2 tooling, no longer it's possible to use `dnx.exe` to run an asp.net app.