# How to determine entry dll for .NET Core web application

Tags: .net-core, iis, dll, web-applications

Say I have a web application with DLLs in the bin laid out like so:

- My.Service.dll
- My.Domain.dll
- Service.Dependency.dll
- etc.

And those DLLs are hosted in IIS web app Service.API. I know by looking at it that My.Service.dll has the entry point (Main method) for Service.API, but that’s just because the app is named similar to the assembly; it could be named Foo or Bar and the runtime would still serve it just the same.

How can I dynamically determine the entry point for a .NET Core web app?

I tried `Get-WebApplication *`; however, that only pulls the app name and directory. I tried using task manager and performance monitor to identify DLLs, but that really only gives me details about the worker processes and the runtime.

Comment: About ASP.NET Core web application entry point, you can have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228846/asp-net-core-1-rc2-web-application-entry-point

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly written in `.deps.json` in the artifact folder.